# What's the command for high approximation up to 50 digits?

Tags: numerics, summation, approximation

I am trying to find the numerical value of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-n^2/\pi^2}}{n^2}$ up to 50 digits. I used

```
NSum[E^(-n^2/Pi^2)/n^2, {n, 1, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

and it came out

```
1.13140507512163903524627544669011642283
```

How to get the other digits?  Thanks

Comment: For this series, I'd just use something like `N[Total@Table[N[E^(-n^2/Pi^2)/n^2, 60], {n, 1, 35}], 50]`, where the truncation at `n = 35` is found with something like `NSolve[E^(-n^2/Pi^2)/n^2 == 1/2*10^-51]`, due to the rate at which the terms decrease.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is `N[Sum[E^(-n^2/Pi^2)/n^2, {n, 1, Infinity}], 50]`, but it fails.

Comment: @Michael E2 Perfect ! thank you.

Comment: `NSum[E^(-n^2/Pi^2)/n^2, {n, 1, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 80, NSumTerms -> 25]` seems to work.

Comment: @Sjoerd Smit another interesting command! thank you. What 25 stands for though?

Comment: According to the documentation (Details section of NSum) it's the "number of terms to use before extrapolation'. I think this might refer to [Richardson extrapolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson_extrapolation) (or something similar appropriate for infinite sums).

Comment: According to docs, it's [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MaclaurinIntegrationFormulas.html) or [whatever this thing is](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WynnsEpsilonMethod.html).
Stephen's only knows what "Alternating signls method" is but my guess summing every second term and simplify.

It is subpar that NSumTerm is a fixed value not depending on precision goal. In general from my play with this integral I'd say yeah, this NSum function is lacking a lot.

Comment: @fqrt `"AlternatingSigns"` is certainly not appropriate here since OP's series is not alternating.

Comment: Isn't it art for art's sake? 50 digits are not from real world (e.g. see [Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant)).

Comment: @user64494 Asking how to get 50 digits of a number in Mathematica is a perfectly valid question. People compute pi up to umpty digits as well; I have no idea what point you're trying to make here.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit: This is another cup of tea: see "Motives for computing π" in Wiki article [Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi). Can you  give applications of  50 digits from the question? TIA. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @user64494 How about just wanting to understand how the software works in general and NSum in particular? That's a perfectly valid reason for wanting this question answered. We have here a straightforward example of the software doing something mildly unexpected; it's perfectly normal to want to know why. Besides, there are many reasons to reject a question, but "I don't think it has a practical application" should not be one of them.